# I have some trouble with ctags

Tags: vim, ctags

I wanna use ctags in my project.and everything goes well during installaion.

```
./configure

make
sudo make install
```

then unzip Taglist. Get tag file in my source path

```
ctag -R
```

add tags path in .vimrc.

```
set tags=/home/lee/program/apue;
set autochdir
```

then begin my c file.

```
vim main.c
```

but when I press ctrl+], i comes "no tag file found".what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the file /home/lee/program/apue really contain your tags (i.e. is it the output file of ctags)?

You should point the `tags` variable in your vimrc to the tags file that `ctags` generates. By default, that's a file named `tags` in the directory where you start the `ctags` command.

Comment: Then you should put `set tags=/home/lee/program/apue/tags` in .vimrc

Comment: What if you type `ctags -R .`? Do you have code in the directory?

Comment: There are several folders int the directory.I try ctags -R again.maybe    comflict with cscope in my computer?

Comment: I don't see a reason why cscope and ctags would conflict. What version of ctags do you use? What version of Vim? On what OS? Could you post the content of `main.c`?

Comment: vim 7.2.330 , Ubunru 10.04, ctags 5.8

Comment: Our setups are almost identical except for the Ubuntu version (10.10 here). `$ ctags -R .` (or `:!ctags -R .` from Vim) works perfectly in any directory containing source files (I have Python, PHP and JavaScript stuff but it supports dozens of languages). I get a `tags` file at the root of the directory which is then used by Vim for code navigation. I have no idea why you don't get a `tags` file, this program is very robust.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the current directory is populated with a bunch of files, the correct command to generate a `tags` file is `$ ctags -R .`. I assume `ctag -R` is a typo.

Is there a `tags` file at `/home/lee/program/apue`? Why is there a `;` at the end?

From your question it looks like you start coding a new file AFTER generating a `tags` file in an empty directory. Since there is no code there is nothing in the `tags` file.

Comment: ; means if tags is not found in current directory , it will try in father directory, and after coding I begin `ctags -R`.